# How to specify a gcs backend from a different project in terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-storage

Fairly simple scenario. I have tf configuration which I am going to use to create a project B from scratch. However, I want to store the state of that new project and all config in a gcs bucket in project A which have existed beforehand.

```
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket  = "I-want-this-state-in-A"
    prefix  = "terraform/state"
  }
}
```

It seems like once upon the time backend config for gcs could include project and region. It seems to no longer be the case.

The project data seems to be fetched from provider block that looks like so:

```
provider "google" {
  region  = myregion
  project = myproject
}
```

Now this is a problem, because all of my terraform resources use this config to create things in  B including B itself. However for some reason provider also decides it's a good idea to store state there. But that bucket doesn't even exist in B at this point yet. Therefore, terraform errors out with a 403.

What are my options here? I've read through terraform docs and there is not a hint from what I've seen on how to force a specific provider configuration onto my backend.

Comment: did u you ever find a solution for this? Or did u came to the conclusion its not possible at the moment?

Comment: see my answer below: "The bucket name in GCP is globally unique..."

Answer (score 0):

The bucket name in GCP is globally unique, therefore it is enough to just use the name of the bucket which lives in another project.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/buckets#considerations

Answer (score -1):

the backend location is set via `gcloud config set project` the provider location sets where the resources are created.